# Regex to match numbers greater than 0, within parenthesis and if the second last character as string

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm not really sure how to do the below in Regex, could you help me?

I'm developing an app that scrape a page, and as a result I get:

```
["(02335E)", "(02743M)", "(00899G)", "(02657J)",
 "(03330B)", "(03359M)", "(Macquarie)", "(00002J)", 
 "(01994M)", "(00401E)", "(Australia)", "(02517K)", 
 "(01545C)", "(03245K)", "(00168J)", "(03258E)", 
 "(00172B)", "(02318F)", "(02778M)", "(03350J)", 
 "(00682B)", "(03265F)", "(from 354 rows)"]
```

How can I match in Javascript Regex only the numbers grater than zero inside these parenthesis when the string ends (before the parenthesis) with any character (like `E`, `M`, `G`, `J`, `B`, `F`, etc)?

So, for example, in the string, `(02335E)`, I would get `2335`, and in the string `(00682B)`, I would get `682`.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You want to get an array of those same elements but with only the non-zero numerical components?

Comment: how this value `"(00401E)"` should be perceived, as `401` or `41` ?

Comment: Hi RomanPerekrest, it should perceived as 401, as only the first two zeros aren't valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"(02335E)".match(/^\(0*([1-9]\d*)[A-Za-z_]*\)$/)[1];
```

Explanation:

- `^`: Start of the string.
- `\(`: A literal left paren.
- `0*`: Zero or more zeros.
- `([1-9]\d*)`: Capture a 1-9, following by zero or more digits.
- `[A-Za-z_]*`: Zero or more word characters (minus any digits).
- `\)`: A literal right paren.
- `$`: The end of the string.

Comment: Haha gotcha. Updated again. Thanks! Coffee is still kicking in this morning. :)

Comment: Thank you so much romellen, it's perfect. I tried really hard to come up with this, but I still have to study a lot Regex.

Comment: Seems like the capture group on this isn't strictly necessary, wouldn't /[1-9]\d*/ perform better?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp
(using a capture group is documented as impacting performance)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this regex on every string:

```
/^\(0*([1-9][0-9]*)[A-Z]\)$/
```

- `^`: start from beginning
- `\(`: match first parentheses
- `0*`: match opening 0s
- `[1-9][0-9]*`: match non-zero number (the answer)
- `[A-Z]`: match character
- `\)`: match close parentheses
- `$`: end at end of string

The first capturing group is your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try out this regex : https://regex101.com/r/iD4aS9/1
The regex used is `\(([0-9]+)\w\)`

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't need anything more complicated than:

```
/[1-9][0-9]*/g
```

It will match 1-9 followed by any number of digits throughout your string.
No need for a capture group.

https://regex101.com/r/nK0qZ7/3

Answer (score 0):

Even though you've already accepted an answer, I just want to add this just for fun since I worked it out.

This particular solution returns a new array to you of a filtered dataset. It will also filter out the ones that do not correspond to numbers such as "(Macquarie)".

```js
var data = ["(02335E)", "(02743M)", "(00899G)", "(02657J)", "(03330B)", "(03359M)", "(Macquarie)", "(00002J)", "(01994M)", "(00401E)", "(Australia)", "(02517K)", "(01545C)", "(03245K)", "(00168J)", "(03258E)", "(00172B)", "(02318F)", "(02778M)", "(03350J)", "(00682B)", "(03265F)"];

var filtered = data.map(function(item) {
  return parseInt(item.replace(/^\((\d+)/, '$1'));
}).filter(num => !isNaN(num));

console.log(filtered);
```